# Connecting Jira Service Desk interface with another ticketing tool

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api, jira-agile

I'm deploying a JSD web interface A that should register tickets for our team.

Today, the team receives also tickets via another ticketing tool B.

I would like to know if there is a way to connect both tools, so the tickets received in tool B can be automatically forwarded to the JSD interface A.